# How to count distinct userid by each dayin Klipfolio?

Tags: klipfolio

I need to count the number of unique values and to group them by day.

For example, I have :

user id     |    Date

1        |           01.-11-2018

1         |         01-11-2018
2           |       02-11-2018

3            |      03-11-2018

1         |         03-11-2018

In result i need

01-11-2018 | 1

02-11-2018 | 1

03-11-2018 | 2

I need do it in Klipfolio

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [GROUPBY()](https://support.klipfolio.com/hc/en-us/articles/215547998-GROUP-GROUPBY-and-COUNTDISTINCT-video-) function with the aggregation in the method parameter set to Count Distinct. For example, if your dates are in column A of a spreadsheet and your values are in column B, your formula would look like this:

```
GROUPBY(@A:A,@B:B,Count Distinct)
```